# How can i extend my ubuntu partition?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am using ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot with windows 10.

[image]

This is how my disk profile in Gparted looks like, how should I use those unallocated 300 GB (or some of it) to extend my ubuntu ext4 partition, what procedure should I follow?

Comment: You could allocate some of that 300G to Windows, and some to Ubuntu. It all depends on how you use either OS. The actual process is pretty easy in your case. Let me know your intent, and I can outline the specific steps for you. Do you have access to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: Yes I have access to Ubuntu live but I don't know how to use gparted.

Comment: I almost missed your reply. Please start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them. I'll show you the steps on how to use gparted. I just need to know more about how you intend to use Windows vs Ubuntu. I don't want to reallocate 300G to Ubuntu, if you also need more space in Windows.

Comment: @heynnema sorry for replying late, but i tried using Ubuntu Live with Gparted, and it worked! Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can resize the partition through Windows 10.  The Disk Management tool should be able to handle this without error.  Make sure you backup your files prior to resize, just in case.

Alternately, you could use a live CD/USB and use Gparted.

Either way, you'll select your partition(sda5) and choose the resize option.

Comment: I would not use Windows. It does not know about ext4 partitions. Use gparted from live installer. You can either move / left & then expand right. The move will take a very long time, and must not be interrupted or it will be corrupted. Make sure both Ubuntu & Windows are well backed up. The expand right will be quick. Alternatively you can move /home to a new partition in the unallocated space or make the unallocated space a data partition, move folders from /home into /mnt/data partition and use that for data. You may have to reinstall grub after the move, but with a move it should be ok.

Comment: No no no. You use Windows Disk Management app to manage NTFS partitions, and gparted to manage EXT4/Swap partitions.